# MVC4: Model's properties are null

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

My MVC4 application has a ListBox and several buttons. When I select an item in the ListBox and press the Delete button and hit the breakpoint in the Delete() method, for some reason all properties of the model object passed to the Delete() method are null. Why is this?

Here is some code:

In the model:

```
public class EdiFileModel
{
    public SelectList EdiFileNames { get; set; }
    public string SelectedEdiFilename { get; set; }
...
}
```

In the view:

```
@model EdiSimulatorWebSender.Models.EdiFileModel
...

@Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedEdiFilename, new SelectList(Model.EdiFileNames, "Value", "Text", Model.EdiFileNames.SelectedValue), new { @Id = "EdiFileNames", @style = "width:Auto;height=Auto;maxHeight:200;" })

<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="submit" value="Send" name="action:Send" />
 <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="action:Delete" />
 <input type="submit" value="Refresh" name="action:Refresh" />
</form>
```

In the controller:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Delete")]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Delete(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
    {
        string selectedFileName = ediFileModel.SelectedEdiFilename;
        ...
    }
```

### Update

I would like also to be able to get on postback not only the Id of the selected item, but the list itself, so that I could use the Id to get the selected item. In my case, the ListBox contains names of the files in a particular folder. I want to be able to select a file, press the Delete button and delete the file. In the Delete() method, I get back the Id, but I would like to get also EdiFileNames.

This is the latest code I have:

Model:

```
public class EdiFileModel
{
    //public SelectList EdiFileNames { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, string> EdiFileNames { get; set; }
    public string SelectedEdiFileId { get; set; }
    public string ResponseContent { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var ediFileModel = new EdiFileModel {EdiFileNames = GetAllEdiFiles()};
        return View(ediFileModel);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [MultipleButton(Name = "action", Argument = "Delete")]
    [ActionName("Index")]
    public ActionResult Delete(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
    {
        string selectedFileId = ediFileModel.SelectedEdiFileId;

        string selectedFileFullName = Path.Combine(SourcePath, ediFileModel.EdiFileNames[selectedFileId]);
        System.IO.File.Delete(selectedFileFullName);            
        return View(ediFileModel);
    }
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var ediFilesSelectList = new SelectList(Model.EdiFileNames, "Key", "Value", Model.SelectedEdiFileId);
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedEdiFileId, ediFilesSelectList, new {@Id = "EdiFileNames", @style = "width:Auto;height=Auto;maxHeight:200;"})
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EdiFileNames)
```

Comment: You haven't passed values for the model to the controller action - none of your input elements that contain values for the model are inside the FORM tags. You need to provide POST information for all properties on the model in order for the MVC model builder to reconstruct your model in a postback scenario - anything outside the FORM tags isn't part of the POST data for anything that triggers that forms submission

Comment: I usually use the Razor helper `@using(Html.BeginForm("x/y/z")) { }` and make sure everything is inside the parenthesis

Comment: You might also want to use `Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Blah)` if you don't want to preserve certain model values in the session state or re-grab them in a controller action - this way they will be injected into the rehydrated model on your controller action.

Comment: @Charleh Thank you very much. I tried that, and now when I hit the breakpoint, SelectedEdiFilename contains the proper Id, but EdiFileNames is still null. Can you tell what is missing? 
Also, if you make what you wrote to be an Answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: HTTP/MVC is essentially stateless, i.e. you need to provide the values to the properties on the model by including the values in your page or by re-getting the values when your controller action is hit. Any POST data during form submission is sent to the controller action - MVC looks at the action and determines the parameter types, then uses a class called the Model Builder to try and re-build your `EdiFileModel` from the post data. You need to include the file list in your postback or re-grab it in the controller. Have you tried including a `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EdiFileNames)` in the form?

Comment: Sorry I might have meant model binder not model builder!

Comment: Worth looking at this to understand how MVC rehydrates your models: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

Comment: @Charleh I tried @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EdiFileNames), but it doesn't work for me when I try to use it in the controller:
       public ActionResult Delete(EdiFileModel ediFileModel)
        {
            var blah = ediFileModel.EdiFileNames;
  
No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to your first issue, you should be including all data that is required in the postback (the form submisson) within the form tags

Anything outside the tags won't be included as part of the post data

There is an MVC helper which you can use for this which makes it nice and easy:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("x/y/z")) 
{ 
  // Html/Razor for your controls/inputs here
}
```

You also need to include any data you want to send back to the model in the postback - if you don't include it it won't be there. You can either get the data in the postback scenario (on the controller action) or pass it back in the post data by including it in the form.

If you want to hide it from the users view, you can make it a hidden element:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeProperty)
```

The second issue you have is that the model binder uses reflection to create instances of your model types to rehydrate your model from the post data.

Full details can be read here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx

This means that any types that you use as part of your model need to have a parameterless constructor in order for the model binder to create an instance and inject the post data.

You are using `SelectList` on your model, this does not have a parameterless constructor and should really only be used to represent a selectable list of items in the view. The model binder can't instantiate an empty `SelectList` to fill with the post data because of this and therefore throws the observed error

In order to make this work, you should use another type that does have a parameterless constructor or create your own type which contains the fields you need. You can probably use `KeyValuePair<K,V>` to represent your selectable data, or you might want to just create an explicit class

Comment: Thanks. Don't I need SelectList as a source for the ListBox?

Comment: Yes but that's done in the view as you already have done you just need to point the select list to the properties on the `IEnumerable` you are using to fill the select list

Comment: Still I'm not sure why you need the list in the model on the post back, what are you using it for? Surely you just use the id the user selected and forget about what was available to them? Or even just get the values again in the action

Comment: I need the list to get the selected element by the id, because if I load the list again, it may have been changed, so the id will point to the wrong element. Or I am missing something?

Comment: I tried again, and the list is empty in my action method. 

@ using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    var ediFilesSelectList = new SelectList(Model.EdiFileNames, "Key", "Value");
    @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedEdiFileId, new SelectList(ediFilesSelectList, "Value", "Text", ediFilesSelectList.SelectedValue), new {@Id = "EdiFileNames", @style = "width:Auto;height=Auto;maxHeight:200;"})
    #Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EdiFileNames)

Comment: Still confused - you mean you want the underlying id behind the selected filename to be passed back to the model? If that's the case, just make sure the selected value part of the select list points at the id (not the file name) and bind that to something like `SelectedFileId` in the model. When the postback hits you get an id in the model instead of the filename they chose. If this doesn't answer the question, update the question with the code and maybe some screenshots or an explanation of where you are getting stuck

Comment: I added stuff to my question. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry David, I'm still not quite sure I follow you as the edit doesn't mention what's actually going into your `Dictionary<string, string>` - what do the key/values represent (I assume the values are filenames, what are the keys?) If you make the key the file id (if not already) and used that, would it not suffice? How do you get the file ids? Where does it come from? If it comes from the server side, why can't you just get the list again during the controller action (or using a function on the model)? Why can't you use the file id from the postback? I'm still not clear on a couple of things

Comment: The first string represents a numeric ID as a string. Why it is a string, doesn't matter. This ID is generated on the fly, thus if I get the list i.e. dictionary again, it may be have been changed from the original dictionary, plus also the dictionary cannot be sorted, thus even if I use the ID, it would not represent the right dictionary entry by the time of the postback.

Comment: These files are on the server right? If so, doesn't a filename represent a file wholly without the need for an id?

Comment: Never mind, I got rid of numeric IDs, as file name is unique withing its folder. Thanks. Still it would be good to know why sending the list back didn't work... maybe another time.

Comment: Might just be the way it was writing it to the page - it's worth looking at the HTML in the browser (view source) and see what MVC did to write the values to the page. Also try hitting F12 in IE (or Chrome works too) and looking at the network chatter, you can see the post data that's being sent to the server to see what it included, it's pretty readable